# How to achieve series of task using bluebird promise?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I've three models:

1. Users
2. Flats
3. Rooms

I want to get information(list) of those `users` who has no `flat` and has `flat` but has zero `rooms` (means room entry not found for particular `flat`).

User Model

```
username:{type: String},
password:{type: String},
...
```

Flat Model:

```
userid: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
flatname:{type: String}
...
```

Room Model:

```
roomid: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Flat' },
roomnumber:{type: String}
...
```

I want to achieve this functionality using `bluebird` module promises.
I've already did :

```
var User = require('../models/User');
Promise.promisifyAll(User);
var Flat= require('../models/Flat');
Promise.promisifyAll(Flat);
var Room= require('../models/Room');
Promise.promisifyAll(Room);
```

Comment: Now, what's your problem? What did you try that did not work? How would your code look without promises? How would your code look if the functions were synchronous?

Comment: Technically I've list of `users` and for each `user` I need to find the list of `flats` and for each `flat` I want figure out number of `rooms`.
I've already solved my problem using traditional callbacks and recursive functions. But I would like to implement it by using latest methodology.

Comment: Please [edit] your code to show us that existing solution.